# C How to exit the command prompt

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program in C that executes another program and doesn't even appear visually, but the way I made the code it for some reason doesn't close at all, only when I press the red x button on the top right, if you know were that is. So here is the code I used, hopefully you can help.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(){
    system("%appdata%/file.jar");
    exit(0);
    return(0);
}
```

As you can see i am not very skilled in this particular programming language.

Comment: Possibly your "system" call doesn't ever return.

Comment: is there any way to fix it? @blue112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. This could simply be done with a simple start or just a batch script. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
main()
{
    system("start %appdata%/file.jar");
    return(0);
}
```

batch script being:

```
start %appdata%/file.jar
```

I don't quite understand why it is needed to be a full binary, but that should solve your problem (assuming this is Windows)

The author then changed the path, seemingly just to get the edit credits. Updated, with improvement.

Comment: @FFlaser run a command with `start` will return to the shell immediately instead of waiting for the command to finish

Comment: @FFlaser then simply use the C code and not the batch file.

Comment: it's just like running the command with `&` at the end in Linux. It's used to running multiple programs at once (multitasking)